# := sql operator in pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, colon-equals

I came across this operator `:=` in a postgresql function:

```
searchsql:= searchsql || ' WHERE 1=1 ' ;
```

I googled but cannot find the answer, what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:=` is the assignment operator in PL/pgSQL

The expression

```
searchsql:= searchsql || ' WHERE 1=1 ' ;
```

appends the string `' WHERE 1=1 '` to the current value of the variable `searchsql`

See the manual for details: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT